# The pointer of LinkedList

Tags: c++

Suppose I am implementing a linked-List project, and I struct a node:

```
    struct node{

    node *prev;
    node *next;
    int data
    };
   node *sentinel;
```

every time I use add() method which keep adding elements in the list like:

```
add(1);  //First node
add(2);  //Second  node
add(3);  //Third node
add(4);  //Fourth node
add(5);  //Fifth node;
```

So after I finish adding, and I want to do a test lets say:

```
node *temp = sentinel->next;
```

So does temp points to the first element?
what if I do:

```
node *temp = (sentinel->next)-next;
```

Does it temp points to the second element now?

If yes, why? And what is the main purpose of

```
node *sentinel;
```

I just start teaching myself C++. I will really appreciate you guys' answers.

```
   Edit:
```

I will have a constructor initialize sentinel as: sentinel = new node();

I will say my add() method is like;

```
add(int data, index)
```

{

```
 sentinel *temp = (sentinel->head); //Lets say temp points to the head of list here.
 node *toAdd = new node(); 
 toAdd->data = data;
 toAdd->next -> temp;
 temp->next = toAdd;
```

}

Comment: Other than the syntax for the struct declaration, this is closer to a C question than C++. But apart from that, *you don't need a sentinel node allocation.* If you're going this route (and I wouldn't; I'd use `std::list<>` or `std::vector<>`, or even `std::deque<>`) then `nullptr` makes a damn-fine sentinel value that is easily testable, and never introduces the somewhat annoying issues "sentinel" nodes always end up surfacing. Q: Is my list empty? A: `if (!head_ptr)`

Comment: The code you presented doesn't contain enough information to answer your question. How is `add` implemented and how is `sentinel` initialized and used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing `node *temp = (sentinel->next)->next;`, assuming there is a third element, temp should point to it. This is because the `sentinel` variable is there to always point to the first element of the list, so we don't lose this pointer. This assumes that your add method works by setting the sentinel value, then the next pointers of the last element.

As an example add method:

```
void add(int data){
   //If the list is empty, set the sentinel value
   if(sentinel == 0){
       sentinel = new node();
       sentinel->data = data;
       sentinel->next = 0;
   }
   else{
      //Else, find the last element
      node* temp;
      //Loops until nodes next is null (node is last node)
      for(temp = sentinel;temp->next != 0;temp = temp->next);

      //Create the next node and set it to next
      temp->next = new node();
      temp->next->data = data;
      temp->next->next = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what i am confused about. if my add method works by setting the sentinel value, finally the sentinel supposes to point to the last element in the list, doesn't it? So if I call sntinel->next after finishing add() method, why wouldn't it point to the last element in the list?

Comment: Your add method should set the sentinel value if it is 0 (null), then you can find the last element (Loop until ->next is 0) or store the last value. If the sentinel is not null, your add method should set the 'next' value of whatever you find to be the last.

Answer (score 3):

sentinel *temp =(sentinel->head);
I think the line not true. Becouse you dos'nt intialize head in struct.
So you just intialize sateniel=null;

```
toAdd->data=data
\\then add
if(sateniel==null)
{
 sateniel=toAdd;
  sateniel->prev=null;
  node *temp=sateniel;
}
else
{
  toAdd->prev -> temp; 
  temp->next = toAdd;
  temp=toAdd;
}
```

then try to travel through the list